# How to config the realm on react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, realm, react-native-ios

I want to use realm in my react-native app. And I executed command `npm install --save realm` then I executed command `rnpm link realm` and these are my code in index.ios.js:

[image]

I encountered a error when I run my app

[image]
And I can't insert neat code in my question, so I insert a picture

Answer (score 0):

OMG , Maybe you need update your moudle if you encounter a problem like this